# Should System.Drawing be run only on WPF's UI thread (C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a C# + WPF based App in Visual Studio, and the advice given was running System.Drawing related methods only on UI thread (e.g. using SynchronizationContext). 
Some of the tasks I use with System.Drawing includes: creating Bitmap images, converting between other image objects and Bitmap objects, using Graphics to paint on Bitmap and saving them.
However, many of the operations can be noticed from GUI window freeze-ups because of the thread being occupied for image operations. This impacts user experience and is a problem for adding more complexity to the project.
So, is it a problem to use other threads doing System.Drawing works? Thanks.

Comment: System.Drawing is WinForms and shouldn't be used at all in a WPF application. Everything you are mentioning here could be done with WPF components. You could then benefit from the fact that some of those components are Freezables, which means they can be created on threads other than the UI thread and after freezing be passed to the UI thread for display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As comments already have pointed out, the *System.Drawing* namespace targets WinForms and only contains its rendering platform specific GDI+ objects. Those objects are not threadsafe. Therefore handling them in a multithreaded context should be avoided as side effects are unpredictable.

Since WPF doesn't use GDI+, it has its own classes equivalent to the *System.Drawing* namespace (e.g., `FontFamily`, `Image`, `Brush`, `ColorConverter`). Most of them are located in the *System.Windows.Media* namespace .

In WPF the thread affinity is enforced by the [`DispatcherObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). Since a `DispatcherObject` is associated with a [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) and a `Dispatcher` object is associated with a thread, we can also speak of *dispatcher affinity*.

All WPF UI objects i.e objects that derive from `UIElement`, also inherit from `DispatcherObject`. `DispatcherObject`implementations can only be accessed on the thread they are created on (dispatcher affinity) otherwise an exception is thrown:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

This also prohibits the passing of `DispatcherObject` instances between threads except this types additionally derive from [`Freezable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=netframework-4.8) e.g., `Brush` or `ImageSource`.
Once those objects are in a frozen state, they are allowed to be transferred between threads as they are now detached from the `Dispatcher` and the dispatcher affinity therefore has been lifted.

This means you can create the image data e.g., `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource` on a background thread, freeze it by calling `BitmapSource.Freeze()` and pass it back to the UI thread to render it with the `Image` control.